# Selected Item in spinner should map the item's name in string-array not the position in drop-down

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-spinner

I have string-array and it's item with their respective names. Like this;

```
<string-array name="languages">
    <item name="en_US">English</item>
    <item name="fi">Finnish</item>
    <item name="fr">French</item>
    <item name="de">German</item>
    <item name="sk">Slovakian</item>
    <item name="pl">Polish</item>
</string-array>
```

And I am trying to change the language of my app with this. What I have done it is working fine. But I want to make it different way. Let's see how I change language when I select the spinner items;

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            switch (arg2) {
            case 0:
                // do nothing
                break;

            case 1:
                setLocale("en_US"); // english
                break;

            case 2:
                setLocale("fi"); // finnish
                break;

            case 3:
                setLocale("fr"); // french
                break;

            case 4:
                setLocale("de"); // german
                break;

            case 5:
                setLocale("sk"); // slovakian
                break;

            case 6:
                setLocale("pl"); // polish
                break;

            case 7:
                setLocale("nl"); // Dutch
                break;
            }

        }
```

Instead of doing this, I want the way to map the selected item (arg2) to the items' name in xml file. why I want this is because in future if someone want to remove or add more lanuages, it should be handy. That's all!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a second array that mirrors your first one, but with the values as the language codes you would like to use. Then calling [`getStringArray(id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getStringArray%28int%29) will give you the `String` array in question. Then just index into it with `arg2` (adding one to it perhaps) to get the locale you're looking for.

For example:

```
String[] locales = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locales);
setLocale(locales[arg2]);
```

But this will only work if you make a new string-array resource filled with your locales!

Comment: Did you mean like this;
String[] language = getResources().getStringArray(arg2);
if(language = en_US){
     
}

Comment: But it does not take in this adapter to get array list in dropdown in spinner:


  
 
But it does not take in this case; ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this, languageArray, R.layout.spinner_row);

Comment: You need to give that method 2 resource IDs. It looks like you're giving it an array and a resource ID. Give it R.array.languages

Comment: Sorry After I accepted the answer is right again I am bothering you back. I am doubting that, what does the selected item reference to in String-array, item name or it's value?

Comment: I believe the item names in the string-array are ignored, so when you get a String array resource, you are getting an array of its values. That's why it is necessary to have 2 string-array resources. One filled with the names of your languages (as you have) and one filled with locales.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

In activity onCreate

```
String[] langArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.languages);
```

inside switch case

```
 String selectedLAnguage = langArray[arg2];
```

Comment: But it does not take in this case;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
    this, languageArray, R.layout.spinner_row);